# I'm unable to get the desired values in my XSLT

Tags: xslt

This is the input :

```
  <Data>
   <A_ID>123456789</A_ID>
   <A_Code>ojhgf</A_Code>
       <A_Rec>
         <inner1>2345</inner1>
        <inner2>14April</inner2>
         <inner3>15November</inner3>
      </A_Rec>
   </Data>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
  <xsl:variable name="AID" select="A_ID" />
  <xsl:variable name="ACode" select="A_Code" />
  <xsl:for-each xmlns:sch="http://schemas.w3.com/" select="//A_Rec">
        <sch:COMPANY>
             <xsl:value-of select="$AID" />
        </sch:COMPANY>
        <sch:COMPANY_CODE>
            <xsl:value-of select="$ACode" />
        </sch:COMPANY_CODE>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

I am trying to get the value "123456789" in the below mentioned line.  $AID should hold 123456789, i am getting the desired value outside the for-each loop though.
But I’m not getting AID and ACode  values inside the for-each loop for Company and company code. What do I do?

Comment: In declaration of AID is it?

Comment: I think it would be better to show the _output you expect_. Asking about an attempted solution (variables and for-each) is pointless because it might lead nowhere. Show us what you are trying to achieve and we can point out how to do it in XSLT.

Comment: I am trying to get the value "123456789" in the below mentioned line.
    <xsl:value-of select="$AID" />
$AID should hold 123456789, i am getting the desired value outside the for-each loop though.

Comment: If I use your stylesheet inside `<xsl:template match="Data">...</xsl:template>`. I am getting your desired output. I am using saxon 6.5.5. What processor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using "Data/A_ID". Assuming that your context node is not "Data" as I see nothing else wrong.

Comment: without the DATA itself I'm getting the value outside the foreach loop. Only inside it its empty

Answer (score 1):

Once created, XSLT variables cannot change their value.
There's a very good SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602884/declaring-a-xsl-variable-and-assigning-value-to-it) that may help you redesign your XSLT.

Edit: Lingamurthy CS has correctly identified an issue with your XPath, but take a look at the SO page I've linked as it still might be useful.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the values of the variables AID and ACode. I'm trying to assign it to different tags? Is there scope for these XSLT variables?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to output `A_ID` and `A_Code` in a different node with a different namespace.

Try this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root xmlns:sch="http://schemas.w3.com/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Data/A_ID|Data/A_Code"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data/A_ID">
        <xsl:element name="sch:COMPANY" namespace="http://schemas.w3.com/">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data/A_Code">
        <xsl:element name="sch:COMPANY_CODE" namespace="http://schemas.w3.com/">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm getting the value outside the foreach loop. Only inside it its empty